# Change syntax highlight for Javascript in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, syntax-highlighting

Can you customise colors of javascript editor in visual studio 2019 to have the same has in vscode, I already look into the police and fonts editor of vs2019 + extensions for more User Tags but none of them change the colors settings.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED2mg.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ECp.png)

Comment: You have something to see ... at my side it is real black and white ... Like Frank said VSCode it is the good solution for the moment

Answer (score 2):

I having same problem, Javascript sytnax color in Visual Studio 2019 seems broken for now:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1127320/lost-typescript-intellisense-and-sytnax-coloring-i.html

The only solution for me is using VSCode..

Answer (score 0):

VS ReShaper extension supports VSCode-like syntax highlighting:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Syntax_Highlighting.html

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wid9D.png

The only caveat being ReShaper is not free and causes lag. However, there are many extensions claiming to replace (parts of) ReShaper and chances are one of these also enables similar syntax highlighting.

Comment: I don't think you mean VSCode ReShaper, the question was about Visual Studio 2019. The product does seem to be for Visual Studio (not VSCode), so I'll check it out. Thank you.